# Applying a style to a link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

I have the following in one of my views:

```
- tickets.each do |t|
  tr
    td class="TicketsDetails" id=t.id style=("color: red; cursor: pointer;")
      = "Ticket Details"

javascript:
  $(".TicketsDetails").on("click", function () {
    ....someaction
  })
```

Instead of using

```
style=(color: red; cursor: pointer")
```

I would like to create a style, for example

```
.ticket-details {
  color: red; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But not sure where how to use it in the view. Any ideas?

## Attempt 1:

I tried the following:

td.ticket-details{id: => "#{t.id}", class: => "TicketsDetails"}

But, I am getting the following error message:

```
Slim::Parser::SyntaxError
```

and it gives me a line number, and a column number, which corresponds to the bolded, italic > below:

```
td.ticket-details{id: =***>*** "#{t.id}", class: => "TicketsDetails"}
```

Comment: remove arrow i guess => "#{t.id}", you used both arrow and symbol

Comment: Huh? No, you can either do :id "#{t.id}" or id: => "#{t.id}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this on your view:

`td.ticket-details{id: "#{t.id}"}`

Assuming that your are using haml. You can define class name with `.classname` and you can also define id with `#idname`. Since your id is dynamic, you can do it like the code above. For more information please check there documentation: http://haml.info/tutorial.html

On slim you can change your code like this:

`td.TicketsDetails id="#{t.id}"  Ticket Details`

On your code:

```
- tickets.each do |t|
  tr
    td.TicketsDetails id="#{t.id}"  Ticket Details
```

Change your css like this:

```
.TicketsDetails {
  color: red; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Note:

if your class your class name is `TicketsDetails` so you need to update your css class name to `TicketsDetails` as well, because in your code above in your css it is `ticket-details`.

Comment: @peaksandvalleys, on your update above why are you still adding `class: => "TicketsDetails"`? It is already defined after td tag.

Comment: What's identified after the td tag, is the style, but not the class that associates with the Javascript function

Comment: Hey @peaksandvalleys I update my answer, please check my the code below.

Comment: I've already tried this, and it does not work. The styling is not applied

Comment: @peaksandvalleys, as what I mentioned above you have 2 class names. Just pick one. In your css  it is `ticket-details` so you need to change it to `TicketsDetails`.

Comment: @peaksandvalleys, I update my answer again for you. Change your css as what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
td.ticket-details{id: => "#{t.id}", class: => "TicketsDetails"}
```

to

```
td.ticket-details{ id: "#{t.id}", class: "TicketsDetails" }
```

Give it a try!